# How to prove $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^s} = \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(1-s)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I meet this question:
let $s \in (0,1)$. Prove
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^s}\ dx= \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(1-s)
$$

I tried this 
\begin{align*}
\cos \frac{\pi s}{2} \Gamma(1-s) = \cos \frac{\pi s}{2} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)\Gamma(s)} = \frac{\pi}{2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(s)}
\end{align*}
Thus it suffices to prove 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^s} 2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(s)\ dx =\pi
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^s} 2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(s)\ dx &= 2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x)\ dx \int_{0}^{+\infty} y^{s-1}e^{-xy}dy\\
&=2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x)e^{-xy}\ dx \int_{0}^{+\infty} y^{s-1}dy\\
&= 2\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{y^{s-1}}{1+y^2} dy\\
&= \sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{y^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+y} dy\\
&= \sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\ B(\frac{s}{2}, 1-\frac{s}{2})\\
&= \sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\frac{\pi}{\sin (\frac{\pi s}{2})}\\
&= \pi
\end{align*}
I basically have two concerns:

1. On $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x)\ dx \int_{0}^{+\infty} y^{s-1}e^{-xy}dy
   = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x)e^{-xy}\ dx \int_{0}^{+\infty} y^{s-1}dy$, how to justify the Fubini's theorem using here?
2. I think my method is too long. Is there any quick method? Maybe using residue theorem?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need residue theorem. Just need a small help from Cauchy’s integral theorem.

Recognize that your integral equals the imaginary part of
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ix}}{x^s}dx$$

Enforcing $x \mapsto iu$,
$$i^{1-s}\int^{-i\infty}_0u^{-s}e^{-u}du=i^{1-s}I(0,-i\infty)$$
if we let $I(a,b)= \int^{b}_au^{-s}e^{-u}du$

By Cauchy’s integral theorem, $$I(\infty,0)+I(0,-i\infty)+\lim_{R\to\infty}\int^0_{-\pi/2}(Re^{it})^{-s} e^{-Re^{it}}iRe^{it}dt=0$$

The third term goes to zero in the limit. The second term is indeed $-\Gamma(1-s)$.

Thus, our original integral equals($i=e^{i\pi/2})$
$$e^{\pi i(1-s)/2}\Gamma(1-s)$$

Taking its imaginary part, we obtain
$$\sin(\frac\pi{2}-\frac{\pi s}2)\Gamma(1-s)=\Gamma(1-s)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}2\right)$$

Therefore,
$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin(x)}{x^s}dx= \Gamma(1-s)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}2\right)$$